# Cannot find symbol - class T

Tags: java, generics

I've this function;

```
  public static T[] addToArray(T item, T... items){
    T[] array;
    int array_size = 1;

    if(items !=null){ array_size = items.length+1; }

    array = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(items, array_size);
    array[array_size-1] = item;

    return array;
  }
```

And I get this error `cannot find symbol symbol: class T`. The idea is to make this method generic. I never worked with generics so I'm guessing I miss some reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method signature for generic method is as follows

```
 public static <T> T[] addToArray(T item, T... items){
      T[] array;
      int array_size = 1;

      if(items !=null){ array_size = items.length+1; }

      array = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(items, array_size);
      array[array_size-1] = item;

      return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to declare the type parameter before the return type of the method:

```
public static <T> T[] addToArray(T item, T... items)
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a generic method?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html#FAQ001)
- [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: I think it's better to link to the official tutorial instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: @maba. Well, I've linked the best reference I know about generics. Anyways, official one is also worth reading.

Comment: Why though? Just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out how to do this coming from a C# background - if the compiler can see T, why do we need the type parameter...

Answer (score 2):

To make a generic method, you need to declare it as taking a generic type parameter:

```
public static <T> T[] addToArray(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you're trying to extend a class that is using generics as well.

e.g. In this example, you're probably missing the `<T>` on the `DogClass`

```
public class PetClass<T> {
...
}

public class DogClass<T> extends PetClass<T> {
...
}
```